# use wireshark to get video url from java application

Tags: wireshark

i was asked recently if its possible to sniff the s3 playback url of a video that is shown in a Java application. So i loaded up wireshark and launched the Java app and started recording.

but i few question came up.

1. how would i filter for video url
2. how do i tell if the packet sniffed belongs to a video stream
3. how can i rebuild the aws s3 url that was picked up. i assume its a private url, would the query parameters providing the access key be picked up?

or if this is at all possible.

thank for any feedback or suggestions.

Comment: This depends on the protocol between the Java application and the server. You can start with the menu item Statistics->Conversations. With a bit of luck the data is transferred in a separate TCP connection.